# Spam Users Posting Links in Answers

Tags: discussion

Over the last few days there have been a series of users ( probably the same person ) posting answers which barely answer the question and then advertising slippers, jeans or some other junk.

One of the user accounts is 
https://security.stackexchange.com/users/1660/slippers

Is there anything that can be done to block this user from posting like blocking their IP for a while?

Here are some examples of the answers from these users I have edited the questions removing the advertising and flagged them as spam.

[Security Architecture - Settings to drive UI and Privileges (Rights) - Role-Based, per User-Account](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/security-architecture-settings-to-drive-ui-and-privileges-rights-role-based/2462#2462)

[Effectiveness of Belarc Advisor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/effectiveness-of-belarc-advisor/2480#2480)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a particularly nasty human spammer from China.

We've been having trouble with this one network-wide.

We banned one `127.0.*.*` range for this user already, I see another one and it is getting banned as well.

Comment: Pardon if this is n00by 'cause I may just be missing something, but I thought the whole 127.0.0.0/8 block was set aside for loopback?  Did IANA open that up more recently due to the IPv4 shortage?  Do people actually get addresses in that range now?

Comment: Yeah - sort of odd.  I'm guessing that @Jeff means a /16 CIDR block

Answer (score 4):

First of all the "answer" these spammers post is *always* (so far as I've seen) not original, they are always quoting a line or a paragraph from one of the other answers - so that it "seems" like the answer is relevant to the question.
(In one case there was no answer so the spammer quoted from the linked vendor's site.)

Whenever you run across these - just flag it for moderator attention as spam, and one of us will hop in and take care of it.
First thing we do - is delete the post.
Second, we merge the user over into a spam collector account - https://security.stackexchange.com/users/1621. This account is locked down, but it helps us keep track of what was going on. 
Third, as @Jeff said I hope they can deal with the issue network-wide...

Thanks for being on top of that!

Comment: oo, correction - looks like that user was removed...

Comment: Should I edit and remove the link? Or just flag as SPAM and leave to you guys?

Comment: @Mark umm... I want to say not to bother editing, but depending on timing it may be a while till a moderator gets to it, so it might be best to just remove it in the meantime... I guess.